# References on density of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I'm interested in books (maybe chapter(s) of a book), articles, results or whatever on the concept of density of subsets $A \subset \mathbb{N}$, often defined as:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|A \cap I_{n}|}{n}$$

where $I_{n} = \{1, 2, ..., n\}$. I've also seen the $\limsup$ being taken instead, defined as upper density. I know a few basic results (that I could prove myself) plus some famous results like [Szemerédi's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem). Is there any sort of reference where I could learn about this in greater detail and scheme?

Comment: Halberstam and Roth's book, Sequences, has a lot to say about densities of integer sequences.

Comment: Tenenbaum's Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory is also worth a look. http://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_analytic_and_probabilist.html?id=DZT5Yqq2DSMC

Comment: I am just seeing now this question: please have a look a this arXiv article https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04664, our motivation was really to found an axiomatic meaning of "upper densities" (which, however, is too general for a generalization of Szemeredi's theorem).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N} \newcommand{\emps}{\emptyset} \newcommand{\sm}{\setminus} \newcommand{\abs}[1]{|#1|} \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}} \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
$This notion is called *asymptotic density* or *natural density*.
If you are using limsup and liminf, it is upper and lower asymptotic density, see e.g.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_density).

Let me start by mentioning some properties of asymptotic density, which I consider useful. Of course any such list is necessarily incomplete, and the choice is matter of opinion. Then I will give several references and I will mention which of these results are contained there.

I will not speak about Szemerédi's theorem - perhaps someone who knows more about this topic will suggest suitable references.

---

#### Basic properties

The following results are obtained easily from the definition and properties of limit inferior and limit superior.

$0\leq \ul d(A) \leq \ol d(A) \leq 1$
If $A\subseteq B\subseteq\N$, then $\ul d(A)\leq \ul d(B)$ and $\ol d(A)\leq \ol d(B)$.
If $A,B\subseteq\N$, $A\cap B=\emps$, then
$$\ul d(A)+\ul d(B) \leq \ul d(A\cup B) \leq \ul d(A)+\ol d(B) \leq \ol d(A\cup B) \leq \ol d(A)+\ol d(B).$$
Consequently, the asymptotic density is finitely additive.
$\ol d(\N\sm A)=1-\ul d(A)$, $\ul d(\N\sm A)=1-\ol d(A)$
For any $a\in\langle0,1\rangle$ there is a set $A\subseteq\N$ such that $d(A)=a$.

#### Alternative definitions

As you already mentioned, the asymptotic density is defined by $\underline d(A):=\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{A(n)}n$, $\overline d(A):=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{A(n)}n$ and $d(A):=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{A(n)}n$, where $A(n):=\abs{A\cap\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$.

Sometimes it is useful to know, that there are different expressions. The first one is about a set given by an increasing sequence of positive integers.

> **Proposition 1.** If $A=\{a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_k<\ldots\}\subseteq\N$, then
> $$
> \begin{gather*}
> \ul d(A)=\liminf_{k\to\infty} \frac k{a_k}\\
> \ol d(A)=\limsup_{k\to\infty} \frac k{a_k}\\
> d(A)=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac k{a_k}
> \end{gather*}
> $$

Sometimes it is useful to be able to compute densities of set consisting of intervals. For example, this is useful when constructing an example of a set which does not have asymptotic density, i.e., a set $A$ such that $\ul d(A) < \ol d(A)$.

> **Proposition 2.**
> Let $a_n$, $b_n$ be increasing sequences of positive integers such that
> $a_n<b_n<a_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\N$. Then for the set
> $A=\N\cap\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty (a_n,b_n\rangle$ we have
> \begin{gather*}
> \ol d(A):=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{A(b_n)}{b_n}\\
> \ul d(A):=\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{A(a_n)}{a_n}
> \end{gather*}

However, both these results are relatively easy to show.

#### Density of some special sets

> **Theorem 3.** If $A=\{a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_n<\ldots\}\subseteq\N$ and the series
> $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{a_k}$ converges, then the set $A$ has
> asymptotic density and $d(A)=0$.

A proof of this result can be found at this site, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5932/theorem-on-natural-density).

> **Theorem 4.** Let $\mathbb P$ denote the set of all prime numbers. Then $d(\mathbb P)=0$.

A very nice proof of can be found in Pete L. Clark's and robjohn's answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82074/percentage-of-primes-among-the-natural-numbers).

#### Comparison with other densities

Some other densities are often studied in number theory. I will mention two of them: logarithmic density and Banach density (also called uniform density).

Let us denote $S(n):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac 1k$ for any $n\in\N$.
Let $A\subseteq\N$. Then the values
$$\ul \delta(A)=\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{k\in A; k\leq n} \frac 1k}{S(n)} \qquad \ol \delta(A) = \limsup_{n\to\infty}
\frac{\sum\limits_{k\in A; k\leq n} \frac 1k}{S(n)}$$ are called
*upper* and *lower logarithmic density* of the set
$A$. If $\ol\delta(A)=\ul\delta(A)$, then this value is denoted
by $\delta(A)$ and called the *logarithmic density* of the set $A$.

> **Theorem 5.**  For any subset $A\subseteq\N$ the inequality
> $$\ul d(A) \leq \ul \delta (A) \leq \ol \delta(A) \leq \ol d(A)$$
> holds. Consequently, if a set has asymptotic density, it also has logarithmic density.

See e.g. the proof at [Planetmath](https://planetmath.org/inequalityoflogarithmicandasymptoticdensity).

*Banach (uniform) density* is defined as follows:
$$\overline u(A)=\lim_{s\to\infty} \max_{t\ge 0}\frac{A(t+1,t+s)}{s}$$
$$\underline u(A)=\lim_{s\to\infty} \min_{t\ge 0}\frac{A(t+1,t+s)}{s}$$
where $A(m,k)=|A\cap\{m,m+1,\dots,k\}|$.

If these values are the same, then $u(A)=\ol u(A)=\ul u(A)$.

> **Theorem 6.** The inequalities $$\underline u(A)\le \underline d(A) \le \overline d(A) \le \overline u(A)$$ hold for every $A\subseteq\N$.
> (Consequently, every set that has uniform density also has asymptotic density.)

The proof of these inequalities can be found e.g. in: Z. Gáliková, B. Lászlo and T. Šalát: [Remarks on uniform density of sets of integers](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/AMI/2002/acta2002-galikova-laszlo-salat.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20170118184959/http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/AMI/2002/acta2002-galikova-laszlo-salat.pdf)).

Note: Several equivalent definitions of Banach density appear in literature.

#### Niven's result

The following result is from the paper
Ivan Niven. [The asymptotic density of sequences](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183516304). Bull. Amer. Math. Soc., 57(6):420-434, 1951; DOI: [10.1090/S0002-9904-1951-09543-9](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1951-09543-9). Often it can be used to show that asymptotic density of some set is $0$.

> **Theorem 7.** If for a set of primes $\{p_i\}$ we have $d(A_{p_i})=0$ for every $i$, and if $\sum p_i^{-1}=\infty$ then $d(A)=0$.

Here, for any $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ and a prime $p$, the set $A_p$ is defined as
$$A_p=\{n\in A; p\mid n, p^2\nmid n\}.$$

Note: If we defined $A_p=\{n\in A; p\mid n\}$ instead of the above result, we would get a weaker result, but the proof is much simpler.

---

#### Some references:

- J. Steuding: Probabilistic number theory. Contains Proposition 1, Theorem 5 ([CiteSeerX](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.118.4755) and [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20040728160527/http://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/%7Esteuding/steuding/prob.pdf))
- Niven I., Zuckerman H.S., Montgomery H.L. An introduction to the theory of numbers (5ed., Wiley, 1991). Chapter 11 is devoted to asymptotic and Schnirelmann density. It contains Proposition 1 and several basic facts on asymptotic density are left as exercises.
- Halberstam H., Roth K.F. Sequences. Asymptotic density and logarithmic are studied in Chapter V. Theorem 3 and Theorem 5 and many further results on asymptotic density are shown here. This books was mentioned in Matthew Conroy's comment above.
  The [Schnirelmann's density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnirelmann_density), which is connected to some results in additive number theory, is studied here too.
- G. Tenenbaum: [Introduction to analytic and probabilistic number theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=DZT5Yqq2DSMC). Contains e.g. Proposition 1, Theorem 5. Several results on asymptotic density (e.g. Theorem 3) are left as exercises. This books was mentioned in Matthew Conroy's comment above.
- Erdos P., Suranyi J. [Topics in the Theory of Numbers](https://books.google.com/books?id=MTefj5-5OwEC) (Springer 2003). Some basic facts on asymptotic density are mentioned here, mostly left as exercises. E.g. Theorem 3, Theorem 4.
- A. Geroldinger, I. Ruzsa: [Combinatorial Number Theory and Additive Group Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=QqSoYzYI7BEC). The authors work mostly with Schnirelmann's density. However, asymptotic density is briefly mentioned, too.

Comment: Beautiful answer! Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, I hope that someone more familiar with this topic will add some other interesting remarks and references - there are plenty of number theorist that frequent this site.

Comment: There appears to be a typo in the statement of theorem 7: it should be $d(A_{p_i})=0$ for every $i$, I'm guessing.
Thanks for the answer, by the way!

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful answer. I'm confused with the notation : $(a_n,b_n\rangle$. What is the definition of the set $(a_n,b_n\rangle$?

Comment: @BijanDatta It is notation for intervals - maybe you are used to a different notation, perhaps you use $(a_n,b_n]$ for the same set. In any case, $(a,b\rangle = \{x\in\mathbb R; a<x\le b\}$.

Comment: I think under alternative definitions, the upper density should have a $\limsup$ and not a $\liminf$.

Comment: @JetChung Thanks, I have edited that one.