# $\liminf_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Na_nb_n\ge\liminf_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\liminf_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, summation, cesaro-summable

Suppose $a_n$ and $b_n$ are uniformly bounded sequences of non-negative numbers. Is it true that
$$
\liminf_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n b_n
\ge
\liminf_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \liminf_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N b_n  
$$

My attempt. The observation should be that $b_n\ge \liminf_{N} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N b_n$ for $n$ large enough. I'm not sure whether this is correct.

This question may be related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509591/is-the-product-of-a-cesaro-summable-sequence-of-0s-and-1s-cesaro-summable/1513611).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

Take $$a_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } n \text{ even} \\ 0 & \text{ if } n \text{ odd}\end{cases}$$
and $b_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=} 1- a_n$, for $n\geq 0$.

Then, for any $N\geq 0$ $$
\sum_{n=0}^N a_nb_n = 0 \tag{1}
$$
and so $\liminf_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n b_n = 0$. But

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N b_n = \frac{1}{2} \tag{2}$$ which implies
$$
\liminf_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \liminf_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N  b_n = \frac{1}{4}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. What if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are all positive and bounded away from zero? This would actually be the case of interest in contrast to what I've written in the question...

Comment: PS: Should I ask a new question or edit this one?

Comment: Replace 0/1 by 1/2: you should still get a counter example. That is, an is either 1 or 2, and bn is either 2 or 1.