# Limit of the Cesaro sum of the product of 0-1 sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cesaro-summable

Assume that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are 0-1 sequences such that
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N b_n = p.
$$
Let also $c_n$ an other 0-1 sequence. Is it true that 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n c_n = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N b_n c_n .
$$
I think it is true because if the first equation is correct, than the limit is also true on each subsequence and in particular in the one where $c_n=1$. Is my argument correct?

Comment: [Not quite a duplicate question, but the answers there also answer this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509591/is-the-product-of-a-ces%c3%a0ro-summable-sequence-of-0s-and-1s-ces%c3%a0ro-summable)

Comment: I think it's worth noting that it's not true that if a sequence has some Cesaro limit, then so do its subsequences. That's a property unique to standard limits.

Comment: @Wojowu yes indeed, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the claimed property does not hold. Take $a_n=1$ iff $n$ is even and  $b_n=1$ iff $n$ is odd.  Then 
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N b_n = \frac{1}{2}.$$
Now if $c_n=a_n$ then $a_nc_n=a_n$ whereas $b_nc_n=0$ and it follows that
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n c_n =\frac{1}{2}\not=0 =\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N b_n c_n .$$

Answer (score 12):

It's not true, let consider

- $a_n=0,1,0,1,...$
- $b_n=1,0,1,0,...$
- $c_n=a_n$