# Asymptotic density and sum of the reciprocals

Tags: number-theory, analysis

Let  A and B be two infinite proper-subsets of the set of positive integers. Let A(n) denote the number of those elements of the set A , which does not exceed n ; we use similar definition for B(n) . Also let lim A(n)/n  > lim B(n)/n , as n→∞

If the sum of the reciprocals of the numbers in B is divergent then can we ever conclude that the sum of the reciprocals of the numbers in A is also divergent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality implies $\lim A(n)/n$ exists and is positive, which is enough to conclude divergence for $A$, regardless of what happens to $B$.

Comment: So, if  lim A(n)/n exists and is > 0 then I can always conclude that the sum of the reciprocals is divergent?

Comment: @Souvik See[Theorem on natural density](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5932/theorem-on-natural-density).